# Way to pass data up to parent middleware?

Tags: go

I've got a pretty solid grip on how to pass data from a handler to the handler it wraps, but is there a go idiomatic way to get something back from the wrapped handler? Here's a motivating example: I have an `accessLogHandler` and an `authHandler`. `accessLogHandler` logs every http request, with timings and other request info such as the currently logged in user's ID (if there is one). `authHandler` is for routes that need a logged in user, it 403's when a user isn't logged in. I want to wrap some (but perhaps not all) of my routes with the `authHandler`, and wrap all of my routes with the `accessLogHandler`. If a user is logged in, I would like my `accessLogHandler` to log the user info along with the access log.

Now, I have a solution I've come up with that I don't like. I'll add the code and then explain some of my issues with it.

```
// Log the timings of each request optionally including user data
// if there is a logged in user
func accessLogHandler(fn http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        accessLog := newAccessLog()
        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), accessLogKey, accessLog)
        fn.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))

        // Logs the http access, ommit user info if not set
        accessLog.Log()
    }
}

// pull some junk off the request/cookies/whatever and check if somebody is logged in
func authHandler(fn http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        //Do some authorization
        user, err := auth(r)
        if err != nil{
            //No userId, don't set anything on the accesslogger
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbiddend)
            return
        }
        //Success a user is logged in, let's make sure the access logger knows
        acessLog := r.Context().Value(accessLogKey).(*AccessLog)
        accessLog.Set("userID", user.ID)
        fn.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
}
```

Basically, what I'm doing here is attaching an `accessLog` struct to my context inside the `accessLogHandler` and inside the `authHandler` I'm reading `accessLog` from the context and calling `accessLog.Set` to inform the logger that a userID is present.

Some things I don't like about this approach:

1. context is immutable, but I'm sticking a mutable struct on it and mutating said struct elsewhere downstream. Feels like a hack.
2. My `authHandler` now has a package level dependency on the `accessLog` package, since I'm type asserting to `*AccessLog`.
3. Ideally my `authHandler` would have some way of informing *any part of the request stack* about user data without tightly coupling itself to said parts.

Answer (score 1):

Context itself is an interface, so you could create a new logger context in the logger middleware that has the methods you would need to get the behavior you are after.

Something like this:

```
type Logger struct{}

func (l *Logger) SetLogField(key string, value interface{}) {// set log field }
func (l *Logger) Log(){// log request}

type LoggerCtx struct {
    context.Context
    *Logger
}

func newAccessLog() *Logger {
    return &Logger{}
}

func accessLogHandler(fn http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // create new logger context
        ctx := &LoggerCtx{}
        ctx.Context = r.Context()
        ctx.Logger = newAccessLog()

        fn.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))

        // Logs the http access, ommit user info if not set
        ctx.Log()
    }
}

// pull some junk off the request/cookies/whatever and check if somebody is logged in
func authHandler(fn http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        //Do some authorization
        user, err := auth(r)
        if err != nil {
            //No userId, don't set anything on the accesslogger
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbiddend)
            return
        }

        //Success a user is logged in, let's make sure the access logger knows
        ctx := r.Context()

        // this could be moved - here for clarity
        type setLog interface {
            SetLogField(string, interface{})
        }

        if lctx, ok := ctx.(setLog); ok {
            lctx.SetLogField("userID", user.ID)
        }

        fn.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! this works pretty well. Using an interface type assertion is great for removing the dep. There is one case this falls apart though. Let's say at any point in the middleware chain I do a `context.WithValue`. From that point on in the chain, my `LoggerCtx` is wrapped and I can no longer access it. So if for instance I wanted another layer down the chain to supply some other data to the logger, I'd have to make sure I am not using `contxt.WithValue` anywhere before that point.

Comment: Correct, that is quite the foot gun. You could keep the interface Idea and just store the logger using `WithValue` but now your package has to know about the key as well as the interface. The approach I take is to have my middleware packages supply connivence functions to access values stored on the context but that does nothing to decouple the packages.