# Golang middleware chain: How can the logger middleware access downstream context information?

Tags: go, go-http, go-context

I'm trying to build a Golang http middleware chain to achieve the following:

- Request logger middleware (with or without authentication information e.g. tenant-id) -> log for every authenticated and unauthenticated request
- Authentication middleware
- Authorization middleware
- Handlers using the user info

All middleware parts pass their information using the context.WithValue function.

The problem I'm currently facing is that the request logger middleware cannot access the user information (to log a tenant id).

I tried using the `request.WithContext` and `request.Context` methods, but `request.WithContext` doesn't change the request in the logger middleware.

How can the logger middleware access downstream context information?

Comment: You want to reinvent echo? https://echo.labstack.com/middleware/basic-auth/

Comment: No, I don't think so. I just would just like a way to display user info inside my logging middleware.

Comment: It could be helpful to see some code that you're using. One pattern I've seen is that the Middleware can either pass the request with context to the Next handler, OR create a new one from the request and pass that. The advantage is the middleware doesn't have access to values added in Next. Mentioned here: https://drstearns.github.io/tutorials/gomiddleware/ Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401197/way-to-pass-data-up-to-parent-middleware